# How to receive SMS sent/delivered feedback for individual SMS after user left activity

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, send, feedback

I have an app that provides SMS messaging. The SMS data is stored in app database. 
The app supports sending to multiple contacts, so when sending an SMS, I dinamically register a different BroadcastReceiver to listen if each SMS was sent (I use each phone number in the String identifying the action in the IntentFilter).

I write the SMS in the database after receiving the confirmation it was sent.

The problem is that if the user leaves the activity before the "sent" Intent is broadcast, the BroadcastReceivers are lost and I cannot capture the "sent" Intent anymore, so the database is not updated. One workaround I chose was to implement onKeyDown() in order to prevent the user from closing the activity before all Intents were broadcasted, but this solution works only with "Back" button - the "Home" button events cannot be captured.

Here is my code:

```
public void sendSMS(String[] phoneNumbers, String message){   

  final String currentMessage = message;
  SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault(); 
  ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);

     for(int i=0; i<phoneNumbers.length; i++){

    for(int j=0; j<parts.size(); j++){

        BroadcastReceiver sent = new BroadcastReceiver(){

             public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {             

                  String[] arg = arg1.getAction().split(KEY_SMS_SENT);  
                  String phoneNo = Utils.setSimpleFormatNumber(arg[1]);
                  String count = arg[0];
                  String parts = count.split(KEY_SMS_PART_NO)[0];
                  String partNo = count.split(KEY_SMS_PART_NO)[1];

                      sentReceivers.remove(this);
                      unregisterReceiver(this); 

                        switch (getResultCode())
                        {
                            case Activity.RESULT_OK:                    
                                if(parts.equals(partNo)){
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), context.getString(R.string.sms_sent_message), 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                                                                     

                           dbAdapter.createSentSMS(KEY_SMS_TYPE_SENT, phoneNo, currentMessage, Utils.getTimeStamp());                                                                       
                                }
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                                if(parts.equals(partNo)){
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), context.getString(R.string.sms_generic_failure_message), 
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                                                             

                                    dbAdapter.createSentSMS(KEY_SMS_TYPE_FAILED, phoneNo, currentMessage, Utils.getTimeStamp());                                                                        
                                }
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:                                
                                if(parts.equals(partNo)){
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), context.getString(R.string.sms_no_service_message), 
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                                                             

                                    dbAdapter.createSentSMS(KEY_SMS_TYPE_FAILED, phoneNo, currentMessage, Utils.getTimeStamp());                                                                        
                                }
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:                              
                                if(parts.equals(partNo)){
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), context.getString(R.string.sms_null_pdu_message), 
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                                                             

                                    dbAdapter.createSentSMS(KEY_SMS_TYPE_FAILED, phoneNo, currentMessage, Utils.getTimeStamp());                                                                        
                                }
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:                            
                                if(parts.equals(partNo)){
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), context.getString(R.string.sms_radio_off_message), 
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                                                         

                                    dbAdapter.createSentSMS(KEY_SMS_TYPE_FAILED, phoneNo, currentMessage, Utils.getTimeStamp());                                                                        
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                };


                registerReceiver(sent, new IntentFilter(String.valueOf(parts.size()-1) + KEY_SMS_PART_NO + String.valueOf(j) + KEY_SMS_SENT  + phoneNumbers[i]));

                //I add the BroadcastReceiver-s to a Vector in order to keep track of them
                sentReceivers.add(sent);

                }
            }
            //I use an IntentService to do the actual sending
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SMSSendService.class);
            intent.putExtra(KEY_SELECTED_PHONE_NUMBERS, phoneNumbers);
            intent.putExtra(KEY_SMS_MESSAGE, message);
            intent.putExtra(KEY_ACTION, KEY_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
            startService(intent);
        }
```

and this is the code in the IntentService:

```
public void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String message, SmsManager sms)
    {           
        ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message); 

        ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPIs = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

        for(int i=0; i<parts.size(); i++){
            sentPIs.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(String.valueOf(parts.size()-1) + KEY_SMS_PART_NO + String.valueOf(i) + KEY_SMS_SENT + phoneNo), 0));

        }

        sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNo, null, parts, sentPIs, deliveredPIs);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Service (not IntentService) in which you could instantiate all the BroadcastReceivers and do the send SMS logic. This way, your SMS-es will be sent in the background and you can intercept the sent/delivered broadcasts.